# protractor is snapping dragged element to mouse pointer instead of dropping it in target container

Tags: drag-and-drop, protractor

```
it('sorts goals', () => {

    browser.sleep(7000)
    let firstGoalCard = $$('.tile-card-slider-container .ng-scope').first()
    let firstGoalContainer = $$('.game-board__title').first()

    browser.actions().
    mouseDown(firstGoalCard).
    mouseMove(firstGoalContainer).
    mouseUp().
    perform();
    browser.actions().dragAndDrop(firstGoalCard, 
    firstGoalContainer).mouseUp().perform()
    browser.sleep(7000)
})
```

dragged element is snapping to mouse pointer instead of dropping in parent container.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Fixed code formatting

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your selectors are correct, you can try to use an external library:

html-dnd: https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-dnd

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Kacper. HTML dnd worked perfectly for me :)